# Generating a symbol that cannot be entered from keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheme

Is there an easy way in python to generate a symbol, that user cannot enter form keyboard.
I know that in scheme exist function `gensym`

Adding info : trying to write part of compiler for scheme. I need to create variable that was never used in program. 
Is there something similar in python?
Many thanks!

Comment: I can enter all characters from my keyboard that the current font supports (left Alt+Keypad on Windows), so I think that's impossible. Or do you just mean characters that can't be typed with a single keystroke?

Comment: `"\x00"` im pretty sure cannot be entered by the keyboard ...

Comment: I don't think the `gensym` tag is appropriate for what you want here... Read the description!

Comment: Unlike Scheme, Python has no concept of symbols, you get to work with strings and namespaces. Can you edit the question to describe what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: What symbol or character does `\x00` correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with scheme but I know a little bit about Common Lisp. I will refer to this knowledge. I think symbols and gensym are roughly the same in both languages.

In python is no concept of a symbol like in common lisp. So if you want to introduce the concept of a symbol you could (for example) write a class. This could look like this:

```
class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

Then (for example) you could say that giving None as the name of the Symbol means that the symbol can't be typed. Then you only need to keep them all (for example in a list or dictionary) and look them up when needed.